# Creating VLAN Bridge for KVM Virtual Machines

Tags: kvm, bridge, vlan, openstack

Original Question:

> I need to run a KVM based VM with a few VLANs going through a single
>   vNIC. How to create a bridge on a Ubuntu/CentOS host machine that can
>   handle VLAN tagged traffic (i.e. how to create a virtual trunk port on
>   a bridge and connect a VM to it in Ubuntu/CentOS)?
>
> P.s.: I created a virtual network (a bridge in the host) via
>   virt-manager, but don't know how to make it VLAN enabled. Any helps
>   would be greatly appreciated.

Updated version:

Here are the network configuration for my two VMs:

```
**VM1**
eth0:     192.168.0.100/24
eth0.100: 10.0.0.100/24 
eth0.200: 172.16.0.100/24


**VM2**
eth0:     192.168.0.200/24
eth0.100: 10.0.0.200/24
eth0.200: 172.16.0.200/24
```

The 192.168.0.0/24 is NAT enabled and can reach out to Internet.

How to configure the host bridge so that the two VMs can talk to each other via their corresponded vlans?

Comment: https://linux-blog.anracom.com/2017/11/20/fun-with-veth-devices-linux-bridges-and-vlans-in-unnamed-linux-network-namespaces-iv/. in short `ip link set brx type bridge vlan_filtering 1`

Comment: @A.B I have just updated my question and hope it clarified my situation. Any inputs on that would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't expect to have two LANs in the same VLAN. what would be the usage of a bridge without a router there? where's the router? anyway I also see it's related to openstack. so there's a lot more here than I could handle. You really should read the link I gave and all the others (there are a total of 8 parts to be found). You'll know all about vlans and how to experimental without even a VM then

Comment: @A.B I was reading a book on openstack and trying to deploy a POC in a virtual environment. The use of VLANs was to separate the control and data networks. In other books, it would use different NICs for the separation, but in this case it used multiple vlans on a single NIC. I will definitely read through the linked article. Thank you so very much!